# Count no. of tokens after tokenization, stop words removal and stemming

Tags: python, string, nltk, preprocessor

I have the following function:

```
def preprocessText (data):
    stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
    preprocessed = []
    for each in data:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(each.lower().translate(string.punctuation))
        filtered = [word for word in tokens if word not in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
        preprocessed.append([stemmer.stem(item) for item in filtered])
    print(Counter(tokens).most_common(10))
    return (np.array(preprocessed))
```

which should remove punctuation, tokenize, remove stop words and stem using the Porter Stemmer. However, it doesn't work correctly. For example, when I run this code:

```
s = ["The cow and of.", "and of dog the."]
print (Counter(preprocessText(s)))
```

it produces this output:

```
[('and', 1), ('.', 1), ('dog', 1), ('the', 1), ('of', 1)]
```

which doesn't remove punctuation or stopwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translate was not working to removing punctuation. Here is some working code.  I made a few changes, the most significant of which is:

#### Code:

```
xlate = {ord(x): y for x, y in
         zip(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))}
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(each.lower().translate(xlate))
```

#### Test Code:

```
from collections import Counter
import nltk
import string

stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
try:
    # python 2
    xlate = string.maketrans(
        string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))
except AttributeError:
    xlate = {ord(x): y for x, y in
             zip(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))}

def preprocessText(data):
    stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
    preprocessed = []
    for each in data:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(each.lower().translate(xlate))
        filtered = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords]
        preprocessed.append([stemmer.stem(item) for item in filtered])
    return np.array(preprocessed)

s = ["The cow and of.", "and of dog the."]
print(Counter(sum([list(x) for x in preprocessText(s)], [])))
```

#### Results:

```
Counter({'dog': 1, 'cow': 1})
```

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'maketrans'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're misusing `translate`. To use it correctly, you'd need to make a mapping table that (as the help string will tell you) maps "Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, strings, or None.". E.g., like this:

```
>>> mapping = dict((ord(x), None) for x in string.punctuation)  # `None` means "delete"
>>> print("This.and.that".translate(mapping))
'Thisandthat'
```

But if you do that to word tokens, you'll just be replacing punctuation tokens with empty strings. You could add a step to get rid of them, but I recommend simply selecting what you do want: namely, alphanumeric words.

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(each.lower() if each.isalnum())
```

That's all you need to change in your code.